# More than one adjective modifying more than one noun

Tags: meaning

I have difficulty when there is more than adjective trying to modify more than one noun.

What is the meaning of this sentence? - "We have new and pre-owned cars and trucks"

Also, where can I obtain practice exercises so I become good at this task?  Thanks

Comment: Welcome Zodiak! This question is too basic here, but you might be interested to visit the new StackExchange proposal "English Language Learners" (ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is not ambiguous: both adjectives apply to both nouns.

Comment: I think that question is not "too basic." The only thing that is too basic (and thus too easy) is the *example* of the OP -- but not its underlying question. There are cases of combinations of two or more nouns with two or more adjectives which cause severe problems.

Comment: "In each room, there are two cabinets. The nurses keep clean sheets and blankets in them." This obviously means the nurses keep clean sheets and dirty blankets inside themselves. This isn't a matter of grammar, it's a matter of logic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there is more than one possible meaning to this sentence:

**Meaning A**: We have ...

- new cars,
- pre-owned cars,
- new trucks,
- pre-owned trucks.

**Meaning B**: We have ...

- new cars,
- pre-owned cars,
- by the way, we also have trucks of all sorts -- in case you are interested.

99% of the people would understand your sentence according to **meaning A** -- much more so, since most people would treat *cars and trucks* in your example as one single composite, in which case you no longer have two nouns but virtually only one.

However, If you were to replace *trucks* by *oranges*, saying "We have new and pre-owned cars and oranges," then you get a different picture and 99,9% of the people would understand that sentence according to **meaning B**. As easy as your example appears at first glance, I am afraid, sentences like this can be more complicated and are indeed context related.

Compare the following sentences:

1. We have new and pre-owned cars and trucks.
2. We have new and pre-owned cars and oranges.
3. We have new and pre-owned cars, and trucks.

Sentence #1 is the sentence of your question and could be regarded as ambiguous, because it is not clear whether the adjectives apply to trucks or only to cars. (However, I will later claim that it is, in fact, not ambiguous. See below.)

Sentence #2 shows a sentence with an identical structure, but I changed trucks to oranges. Here it would be clear from the context, that "new" and "pre-owned" most likely do not apply to oranges, but only to cars.

Sentence #3 shows how adding a comma can help to clarify the meaning. This sentence is identical in meaning with the **Meaning B** above.

So, why did I just say that in my opinion sentence #1 is not ambiguous? If people would always add that comma of sentence #3, we could easily distinguish in writing between **Meaning B** and **Meaning A**: With that comma (= sentence #3) we get **Meaning B**. Without that comma (= sentence #1) we get **Meaning A**.

This also entails that sentence #2 is, in terms of punctuation, sort-of wrong, as it actually needs a comma before "and oranges" -- a comma which is almost implicit through the context, though.

*A note with respect to what has been said in the comments: In a previous version of this answer, I used the term Oxford comma as a means to name that comma of sentence #3, because that comma serves a similar purpose, so I borrowed the name "Oxford comma". It has ben suggested, though, to avoid that term altogether and I edited the answer accordingly.*

Comment: That is not an Oxford comma!!!!

Comment: @tchrist : An Oxford comma is usually used in cases of a series of at least three items before the last conjunction when appropriate. You are right, the comma I am talking about here is -- strictly speaking -- not an Oxford comma, but it serves a similar purpose. Therefore, I used its name in lack of another fancy comma name.

Comment: Clint, shouldn't it be more proper to say "We have new and pre-owned cars, other than truck" in your "A" case. If so, can "B" case be what 99% of people understands hearing the OP's example? Lastly, since tchrist is right, why don't you edit the question avoiding completely to use "Oxford comma", rather than introducing a new definition of this famous concept?

Comment: @Carlo_R. : Yes this is exactly what I meant. Good point! I made it more clear and altered the answer accordingly, leaving out the *Oxford comma*.

Answer (score 0):

Note, however, that “We have ripe and tasty apples and oranges” means that we have ...

- apples that are ripe and tasty, and
- oranges that are ripe and tasty.

You always have to consider the context.