# If two or more nouns follow a single adjective, do they all share the same attribute?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, colors

In the following example,

> Our goal is to create an overview of this field of research and add
>   our own perspective on the study of **green crime, law, and justice** to
>   that literature. [excerpt](http://www.ucpress.edu/book.php?isbn=9780520289635)

Is *green* an adjective used only for crime, or for law and justice too?

Similar questions [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/two-adjectives-for-two-nouns) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106932/more-than-one-adjective-modifying-more-than-one-noun) ask about more than one adjective + more than one noun, and the answers seem to be "look at the context".

So, in the context mentioned above, how should we interpret it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the similar questions say, it depends upon context. We need to ask ourselves: does it make sense for all of these things to be green, or just crime?

In this context, green refers to [green criminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_criminology), which is criminology having to do with the environment.

Since the title of the book is "green criminology", they're probably not going to be talking much about law and justice not having to do with the environment, so it doesn't make much sense for them to say they'll be talking about green crime, but law and justice in the general sense. Therefore, I'd say that "green" here most likely applies to all of the nouns.